# Difficulties Starting X Session

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, xorg, fonts

I've had a hard time starting an X session on an account on my Kubuntu 18.04 machine ever since I installed a font under that user's account. This happened quite some time ago and I can't remember the name of the font anymore or exactly how I went about installing it, but it was a font that was meant to be optimized for programming and I wanted to use it with VSCode.

My workaround for the past 1+ years has been to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> key to get to a terminal, log in as the user in question and manually start an X session using the `startx` command. When I do this have, I have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> several times (usually about 3) in order to get the X session to eventually start.

If I just execute `startx` and leave it alone I think I eventually get an error about a failure to get a lock on some kind of resource.

If I try to start an X session the normal way by logging in when the computer starts up it just hangs at the login screen (although everything appears normal) and I eventually have to hard reboot the computer.

Logging in as other users works just fine. I've tried several times to look through the X logs to see what the problem may be, but I just don't understand them well enough to get things back where they need to be.

Any thoughts?

Edit per comment:

There are no error messages that I am able to capture. Here is what I am able to find in the X log.

```
~: !1391
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep EE
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
~: !1392
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep WW
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     6.866] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     6.866] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     6.866] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     6.866] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     6.866] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     6.900] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     6.901] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    16.056] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[    16.056] (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include relevant error messages / log extracts - even if you don't understand them well enough to learn anything from them, perhaps someone here will

Comment: I too get the same warnings re. fonts but none of the other WW entries.

Comment: Re. "it just hangs at the login screen", does the login screen appear normal? Are the fonts normal? And please mention your Kubuntu version!